Check if HashSet contains enum field without explicit value
Imagine this code (won't work):
use std::collections::HashSet;

#[derive(PartialEq, Hash, Eq)]
pub enum SomeEnum {
    One(u32),
    Two(u32),
}

fn main() {
    use SomeEnum::*;
    let set = HashSet::from([One(123), Two(321)]);
    if set.contains(&One) {
        // do something
    }
}

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bdf723db587a6d6f96d99ef31e45350c
I want to check if my data set contains an enum variant but without checking the specific value in it. Is this possible somehow?

Obviously impossible without linearly iterating over the set.

Can you explain a little more how this set is used?  Is it ever required to distinguish between elements of the same enum variant but different field values?  The replies you have received so far assume so, which is indeed probably what you were asking; but perhaps you actually just want a set of Disciminant<SomeEnum> or similar?

You can iterate over keys of a HashSet with HashSet::iter. Then it is simply a matter of checking if any one of them matches given enum variant. This is of course a linear time complexity operation.
use std::collections::HashSet;

#[derive(PartialEq, Hash, Eq)]
pub enum Foo {
    One(u32),
    Two(u32),
}

pub fn contains_one(set: &HashSet<Foo>) -> bool {
    set.iter().any(|k| matches!(k, &Foo::One(_)))    
}

fn main() {
    use Foo::*;
    let set = HashSet::from([One(123), Two(321)]);
    assert!(contains_one(&set));
}

Note that variant One is hardcoded in contains_one function. If you want to be "generic" over contained variant you must use a macro instead.
macro_rules! contains_variant {
    ($set:expr, $variant:pat) => {
        $set.iter().any(|k| matches!(k, $variant))
    }
}

fn main() {
    use Foo::*;
    let set = HashSet::from([One(123), Two(321)]);
    assert!(contains_variant!(set, &One(_)));
}


I used HashSet because I thought I could check members wihtout iterating but I understand why this is not working. I like this solution. It also works with Vec.


Is this possible somehow?

Not with a hashset. By definition a hashset needs a value to hash (then test for equality), so you can't test against a set of values.
This would be possible, kind-of, using a btree set: btrees support range requests, so you can get the range starting at the lowest value for the variant you're looking and see if the first entry is of the expected variant, or get the range for the entire variant and see if it's non-empty: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=72e3051c8f8a99206729cce4305ff153
println!("lower bound, check for first value");
println!("\thas a one? {}", matches!(set.range(One(0)..).next(), Some(One(_))));
println!("\thas a three? {}", matches!(set.range(Three(0)..).next(), Some(Three(_))));

println!("full bounds, check for any value");
println!("\thas a one? {}", set.range(One(0)..=One(u32::MAX)).next().is_some());
println!("\thas a three? {}", set.range(Three(0)..=Three(u32::MAX)).next().is_some());

lower bound, check for first value
    has a one? true
    has a three? false
full bounds, check for any value
    has a one? true
    has a three? false


This answer is simply incorrect. You can iterate over keys and do a linear scan. It is true that you cannot do that with a constant lookup, but OP asked simply about possibility.
